# React icons: Which import should I use?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, icons, react-icons

I'm a bit confused. In my web project, I'm using React and for iconography, I'm using the [React Icons](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/) library.

The thing that confuses me is: Every time I want to use an icon, the IDE (in my case JetBrains WebStorm) suggests two available import locations.

[image: Import suggestions in the IDE]

Apparently, the icon exists in the parent `all` directory, but also in a specific directory with the same name the icon has.

```
import { FaStackOverflow } from "@react-icons/all"
import { FaStackOverflow } from "@react-icons/all-files/fa/FaStackOverflow"
```

### Which one should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Import icons from `all`, not from a subdirectory

The following hint is given in the [docs](https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons):

> NOTE: each Icon package has its own subfolder under react-icons you import from.

Also, after some experiments, I realized that using the icon from the `all` directory is the right one. I had issues when styling the icon (using a global class name provided in the `<IconContext.Provider>` parent element), so I changed the import location, and voilà, it worked!

Here is a demo. I'm using the following CSS to style the icon.

```css
.icon {
    outline: 1px solid hotpink;
}
```

This is the JSX code:

```html
<IconContext.Provider value={{ className: 'icon' }}>
  <FaStackOverflow />
</IconContext.Provider>
```

When importing the icon from the subdirectory, the styles are not applied correctly:

```
import { FaStackOverflow } from "@react-icons/all-files/fa/FaStackOverflow"
```

[image: icon imported from wrong directory]

In contrast, this is the import from the correct location (directory `all`).

```
import { FaStackOverflow } from "react-icons/all"
```

[image: icon imported from correct directory]